# Mensagem de sucesso ao cadastrar no BD

Tags: php, javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap

O script abaixo funcionava com a versão mais velha do js e Bootstrap, porém depois que passei a utilizar a mais recente ele parou... Utilizo ele para retornar a mensagem do formulário!
Se alguém poder me ajudar, entendo pouco de json e js...

```
// Quando carregado a página
$(function ($) {

// Quando enviado o formulário
$('#NovaEntrada').on('submit', function () {

    // Armazenando objetos em variáveis para utilizá-los posteriormente
    var formulario = $(this);
    var botao = $('#salvar');
    var mensagem = $('#mensagem');

    // Exibindo indicador de carregamento (Bootstrap)
    // Docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons
    botao.button('loading');

    // Enviando formulário
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({

        // Definindo tipo de retorno do servidor
        dataType: 'json',

        // Se a requisição foi um sucesso
        success: function (retorno) {

            // Se cadastrado com sucesso
            if (retorno.sucesso) {
                // Definindo estilo da mensagem (sucesso)
                mensagem.attr('class', 'alert alert-success');

                // Limpando formulário
                formulario.resetForm();


            //recarrega a pagina
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.reload(1);
            }, 1000);
            }
            else {
                // Definindo estilo da mensagem (erro)
                mensagem.attr('class', 'alert alert-danger');
            }

            // Exibindo mensagem
            mensagem.html(retorno.mensagem);

            // Escondendo indicador de carregamento
            botao.button('reset');

        },

        // Se houver algum erro na requisição
        error: function () {

            // Definindo estilo da mensagem (erro)
            mensagem.attr('class', 'alert alert-danger');

            // Exibindo mensagem
            mensagem.html('Ops, algum erro foi encontrado!!!');

            // Escondendo indicador de carregamento
            botao.button('reset');
        }

    });

    // Retorna FALSE para que o formulário não seja enviado de forma convencional
    return false;

 });

 });
```

formulário

```
<form id="NovaEntrada" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="ajax/Cadastrar.php"> 
Obs.:Não adicionei os inputs para não ficar longo o codigo 
<input type="submit" id="salvar" class="btn btn-primary" value="Salvar" data-loading-text="Salvando..."/>
 <!---- exibe a mensagem do script -----> 
 <div id="mensagem"></div>
</form>
```

retorno.php

```
// Função que retorno um JSON com a propriedade sucesso e mensagem
function retorno($mensagem, $sucesso = false) 
{
// Criando vetor com a propriedades
$retorno = array();
$retorno['sucesso'] = $sucesso;
$retorno['mensagem'] = $mensagem;

// Convertendo para JSON e retornando
return json_encode($retorno);
}
```

ajax/Cadastrar.php

```
// Executando e exibindo resultado
echo ($stmt->execute()) ? retorno('Cadastrado com sucesso', true) :  retorno($stmt->errorInfo());
```

Comment: da um `echo()` no `json_encode()` e testa pra ver

Comment: Ele retorna direitinho a mensagem, o problema parece que o script não recebe a msg

Comment: resultado do echo: {"sucesso":true,"mensagem":"Cadastrado com sucesso"}

Comment: deve ser problema com nomenclatura igual, vc tem dois `mensagem` no código `Jquery`, tenta mudar um deles para ver

Answer (score 1):

mudei o nome da variável `mensagem`, que é referente a tag que vai receber a mensagem para `campo_mensagem`:

```
// Quando carregado a página
$(function ($) {

// Quando enviado o formulário
$('#NovaEntrada').on('submit', function () {

    // Armazenando objetos em variáveis para utilizá-los posteriormente
    var formulario = $(this);
    var botao = $('#salvar');
    var campo_mensagem = $('#mensagem');

    // Exibindo indicador de carregamento (Bootstrap)
    // Docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons
    botao.button('loading');

    // Enviando formulário
    $.ajax({

        url:'destino.php',//url do arquivo que vai receber os dados
        // Definindo tipo de retorno do servidor
        dataType: 'json',

        // Se a requisição foi um sucesso
        success: function (retorno) {

            // Se cadastrado com sucesso
            if (retorno.sucesso) {
                // Definindo estilo da mensagem (sucesso)
                campo_mensagem.attr('class', 'alert alert-success');

                // Limpando formulário
                formulario.resetForm();


            //recarrega a pagina
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.reload(1);
            }, 1000);
            }
            else {
                // Definindo estilo da mensagem (erro)
                campo_mensagem.attr('class', 'alert alert-danger');
            }

            // Exibindo mensagem
            campo_mensagem.html(retorno.mensagem);

            // Escondendo indicador de carregamento
            botao.button('reset');

        },

        // Se houver algum erro na requisição
        error: function () {

            // Definindo estilo da mensagem (erro)
            campo_mensagem.attr('class', 'alert alert-danger');

            // Exibindo mensagem
            campo_mensagem.html('Ops, algum erro foi encontrado!!!');

            // Escondendo indicador de carregamento
            botao.button('reset');
        }

    });

    // Retorna FALSE para que o formulário não seja enviado de forma convencional
    return false;

 });

 });
```

Comment: Ainda não foi amigo, no console do navegador deu esse erro: TypeError: $(...).ajaxSubmit is not a function... eu acho que deve ser a função que está gerando incompatibilidade, pois com versão do js 2.3 funciona

Comment: sim, usa `$.ajax()` apenas

Comment: resposta ta editada

Comment: Já começou a dar certo brother, retornou a msg Ops, algum erro foi encontrado, porem o erro e na função... o código php retorna sucesso

Comment: na função do erro coloca um parametro `error:function(e){` e da um `console.log(e)` para ver o que deu errado